# jQuery - getting custom attribute from selected option

Tags: jquery

Given the following:

```
<select id="location">
    <option value="a" myTag="123">My option</option>
    <option value="b" myTag="456">My other option</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="setMyTag" />

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#location").change(function(){
            var element = $(this);
            var myTag = element.attr("myTag");

            $('#setMyTag').val(myTag);
        });
    });
</script>
```

That does not work...
What do I need to do to get the value of the hidden field updated to the value of myTag when the select is changed.  I'm assuming I need to do something about getting the currently selected value...?

Answer (score 597, accepted):

You're adding the event handler to the `<select>` element.
Therefore, `$(this)` will be the dropdown itself, not the selected `<option>`.

You need to find the selected `<option>`, like this:

```
var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('mytag');
```

Comment: Made my all-nighter crunch-time so much easier... +1!

Comment: Note, if you're looking to retrieve the option that was selected when the page loaded (not the currently selected option) you can use $('option[selected]', this) instead (note: if no option was selected when the page loaded, that will return no matches, so calling attr() on that will result in undefined. easy to test for and deal with of course.)

Comment: For anyone looking for this answer >= 2022, I think the syntax changed at some point. I got it to work with :checked instead of :selected with some help from this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104891/4172413

Answer (score 59):

Try this:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#location").change(function(){ 
        var element = $(this).find('option:selected'); 
        var myTag = element.attr("myTag"); 

        $('#setMyTag').val(myTag); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 34):

That because the element is the "Select" and not "Option" in which you have the custom tag.

Try this: `$("#location option:selected").attr("myTag")`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Short and simple answer. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you have many selects. This can do it:

```
$('.selectClass').change(function(){
    var optionSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('optionAtribute');
    alert(optionSelected);//this will show the value of the atribute of that option.
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$("#location").change(function(){
            var element = $("option:selected", this);
            var myTag = element.attr("myTag");

            $('#setMyTag').val(myTag);
        });
```

In the callback function for `change()`, `this` refers to the select, not to the selected option.

Answer (score 7):

You're pretty close:

```
var myTag = $(':selected', element).attr("myTag");
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest one,

```
$('#location').find('option:selected').attr('myTag');
```

Answer (score 5):

Simpler syntax if one form.

`var option = $('option:selected').attr('mytag')`

... if more than one form.

`var option = $('select#myform option:selected').attr('mytag')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the entire script with an AJAX call to target a single list within a page with multiple lists.  None of the other stuff above worked for me until I used the "id" attribute even though my attribute name is "ItemKey".  By using the debugger

[Chrome Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prtT9.png)

I was able to see that the selected option had attributes: with a map to the JQuery "id" and the value.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="List1"></select>
<select id="List2">
<option id="40000">List item #1</option>
<option id="27888">List item #2</option>
</select>

<div></div>
</body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//get a reference to the select element
$select = $('#List1');

//request the JSON data and parse into the select element
$.ajax({
url: 'list.json',
dataType:'JSON',
success:function(data){

//clear the current content of the select
$select.html('');

//iterate over the data and append a select option
$.each(data.List, function(key, val){
$select.append('<option id="' + val.ItemKey + '">' + val.ItemText + '</option>');
})
},

error:function(){

//if there is an error append a 'none available' option
$select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
}
});

$( "#List1" ).change(function () {
var optionSelected = $('#List1 option:selected').attr('id');
$( "div" ).text( optionSelected );
});
</script>
</html>
```

Here is the JSON File to create...

```
{  
"List":[  
{  
"Sort":1,
"parentID":0,
"ItemKey":100,
"ItemText":"ListItem-#1"
},
{  
"Sort":2,
"parentID":0,
"ItemKey":200,
"ItemText":"ListItem-#2"
},
{  
"Sort":3,
"parentID":0,
"ItemKey":300,
"ItemText":"ListItem-#3"
},
{  
"Sort":4,
"parentID":0,
"ItemKey":400,
"ItemText":"ListItem-#4"
}
]
}
```

Hope this helps, thank you all above for getting me this far.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on('change', '#location', function(e) {

 var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('myTag');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var optionAttr1 = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("myTag");
var optionAttr = $('#location option:selected').attr("myTag");
```

Comment: `$('[name="bulk_vendor_agent[0]"]').find('option:selected').data("name")` solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try This Example:

```
$("#location").change(function(){

    var tag = $("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]", this).attr('mytag');

    $('#setMyTag').val(tag); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one as well with `data-myTag`

```
<select id="location">
    <option value="a" data-myTag="123">My option</option>
    <option value="b" data-myTag="456">My other option</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="setMyTag" />

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#location").change(function(){
           var myTag = $('option:selected', this).data("myTag");

           $('#setMyTag').val(myTag);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stright forward way is :

Get selected option attribute value:

```
var selectedOptionAttributeValue =   $('#location option:selected').attr('myTag');
```

Get Selected Text:

```
 var selectedOptionText = $('#location').text();
```

Get selected value:

```
var selectedOptionValue = $('#location').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call according to dynamic row ID use:

```
var data = $(`#var_name_${row_id} option:selected`).attr('value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solutions were not working properly, So I have got a solution that worked for me, Putting this if it helps anyone.

```
var option = $('#location').find(":selected").attr('myTag')
```