# Jquery select change

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

```
<select id="Nazione" name="Nazione">
    <option prefix='+93' value='AF' >Afghanistan </option>
    <option prefix='+355' value='AL' >Albania </option>
    <option prefix='+213' value='DZ' >Algeria </option>
    <option prefix='+376' value='AD' >Andorra .... etc
</select>
```

and this js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#Nazione').change(function(){

        alert( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('prefix') );
        alert( $(this).attr('prefix') );
    });
  });
```

I have alert NULL... 
WHy?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/trxZK/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wzzMm/ works here in Chrome!

Comment: You have not closed the option tag for the last entry.Is that a typo or mistake in the code?

Comment: I believe it is the second `alert` that is causing the issues.

Comment: This works for me _if I ask jsfiddle for jQuery 1.6_. Both alerts give null on jQuery 1.5.2.

Comment: TRY WITH JQUERY 1.5.2 ....... BUG??

Comment: The problem is with your attribute name and not your code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is fine. Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hKktc/1/

The reason you're not getting a value for the second alert call is because the attribute `prefix` doesn't exist for the `select` and only exists for the `option`

Comment: That's a really weird issue. The problem is not with the code, rather with the attribute name. If you change it to `prefix1` it works : http://jsfiddle.net/hKktc/7/ I don't know whether it's a bug or something else

Comment: `prefix` might be a keyword! :)

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `$(this)` refers to the `<select>`, not the option. The `prefix` attribute does not exist on the `<select>`

This will cause the problem with the second example.

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd `alert` will return null, because `<select>` has no attribute `prefix`.

Answer (score 1):

What is it you are expecting exactly?

I find that the second alert - `alert( $(this).attr('prefix') );` is the one causing a problem. 
As is, you get an alert of the prefix number, then an alert of null (caused by the second alert).

Comment: Following the tip off by @JohnP above - it does indeed work perfectly if you change the atrtibute `prefix` to something else. I presume `prefix` is reserved. 
Also, this is a bit more pretty - 
    `$(document).ready(function() {  
     $('#Nazione').change(function(){
      alert ( $('option:selected', this).attr('prefix1') );
     });
    });`

That code by @SLaks in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option).

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted `.val()` not `.attr('prefix')`, to obtain selected value of `<select>`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#Nazione').change(function(){

        alert( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('prefix') );
        alert( $(this).val('prefix') );
    });
  });
```