# jQuery selector dont work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, struts2

hi im starting to learn jquery, i read tutorial and i constructed my code but i wonder why this code does not work on my page:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#storage").change(function(){
    alert("sample ng onchange");    
  });
</script>


<tr><td><s:text name="label.storageArea" /></td>
<td><s:select  name="mediaBean.storageAreaDesc" 
            list="storageAreaList"              
            value="%{mediaBean.storageAreaDesc}" 
            size="1" style="width:155px;" 
            theme="simple" id="storage" />
</td>   
</tr>
```

please help. thank you.

Here is the resulting HTML of  tag:

```
<select name="mediaBean.storageAreaDesc" size="1" id="storage" style="width:155px;">
    <option value="1 - Storage 1" selected="selected">1 - Storage 1</option>
    <option value="2 - Storage 2">2 - Storage 2</option>
    <option value="3 - Storage 3">3 - Storage 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to use document ready handler. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Add to that, with `<s:select>` not being a standard HTML element, if it shows in the page, support for selecting it by ID may well depend on how lax the browser is about that stuff.  If the element is expanded at runtime by your framework, you might want to show the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your script is **before the HTML** , encase that in `DOM ready handler` . This makes sure the script runs after the DOm loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#storage").change(function(){
         alert("sample ng onchange");    
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Does that mean that script after the HTML is guaranteed to execute after the DOM has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to wrap your js code in a  jquery document ready block

see http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and [Jquery select change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961957/jquery-select-change)

Comment: sorry i was not able to accept two answers but your solution is also correct. thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

first, put all your js at the bottom of your page and use this to wrap your code

```
;(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready. 
        // Use $() w/o colliding with other libs;
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is no real reason to put it at the bottom of the page if it is wrapped by a `$(document).ready` handler.

Comment: it's just a common good practice, http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: Yes, but from your comment it sounded to me like it was a requirement to make the code work, but that is not the case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855077/does-putting-scripts-on-the-bottom-of-a-web-page-speed-up-page-load for more information on why it might be a good idea, but not a must-have.