# Pass two value from select box once its get selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am having a requirement to get two relative values when changing a select box. Am having a multiple select box which containing some options used to present user resources. Some options are representing parent resources. So I need to get the selected value as well as whether its a parent or not.

```
<select class="filtered remaining" onchange="check_options(this)" id="multi-select-left" multiple="multiple" style="height: 15em;">
    <option parent="0" value="1">User</option>
    <option parent="1" value="2">User-Login</option>
    <option parent="1" value="8">User-Logout</option>
    <option parent="1" value="11">User-Register</option>
    <option parent="0" value="3">Backend</option>
    <option parent="0" value="4">Settings</option>
    <option parent="4" value="5">Settings-Edit</option>
    <option parent="0" value="6">Category</option>
    <option parent="6" value="7">Category-add</option>
    <option parent="0" value="12">logger</option>
    <option parent="0" value="13">brands</option>
    <option parent="0" value="14">User-Role</option>
</select>
```

is there anyway to get the `parent="0"` value when selecting a option. I have tried dozen of things, nothing worked. :(

This is my check_options method

```
function check_options(val)
{
var test = $(val).children("option").filter("parent").text();
alert(test);

}
```

Comment: "a dozen of things", like what? Post some code please!

Comment: post what you tried....i mean the code

Comment: where is the `check_options` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - getting custom attribute from selected option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/frFa9/

```
 $('#multi-select-left').change( function() {
    var $t = $(this);    
    var tVal = $t.val();    
    var tParent = $t.find('option:selected').attr('parent');

    alert( 'tVal: ' + tVal);
    alert( 'tParent : ' + tParent );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaheer, you took off almost an nightmare from me.

Answer (score 0):

can you please make option

```
<option value="0_1">User</option>
```

and explode it when you requied

Comment: Thank you @Shakti Patel, am having that option in mind, but first I tried to do it in easier way. If  theres no anyway to get this parent value, ofcourse I have to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function check_options()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("multi-select-left");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) 
    {
        if(x.options[i].selected ==true)
        {
            // alert(x.options[i].value);
             alert(x.options[i].getAttribute('parent'));
        }
    }
}
</script>
<select class="filtered remaining" onchange="check_options();" id="multi-select-left" multiple="multiple" style="height: 15em;">
    <option parent="0" value="1">User</option>
    <option parent="1" value="2">User-Login</option>
    <option parent="1" value="8">User-Logout</option>
    <option parent="1" value="11">User-Register</option>
    <option parent="0" value="3">Backend</option>
    <option parent="0" value="4">Settings</option>
    <option parent="4" value="5">Settings-Edit</option>
    <option parent="0" value="6">Category</option>
    <option parent="6" value="7">Category-add</option>
    <option parent="0" value="12">logger</option>
    <option parent="0" value="13">brands</option>
    <option parent="0" value="14">User-Role</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get parent value of selected option by this script:

```
function check_options(val)
{
var test = $(val).find(":selected").attr("parent").value;
alert(test);
}
```

Comment: the last `.value` is not valid, `attr()` already returns the value