# How to get selected option element attr in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, attr

I want to get attribute value of selected option element.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#select_element").val().attr("val");
```

**HTML:**

```
 <select id="select_element" class="selectpanel">
     <option val="x">element1</option>
     <option val="y">element2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Remove the `attr` method and use `value` attribute not `val`.

Comment: I Googled the title of your question and found the answer to your problem, you should do the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)

Comment: `val` is not a valid attribute for `option` elements. The attribute is `value`. If you want a custom attribute, use a `data-` prefix.

Comment: T.J. Crowder thanks for information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$('#select_element option:selected').attr('val');
```

**Or**

```
$('#select_element option:selected').val();
```

both are valid!

Comment: Yes its work.thanks 
var id = $('#ilce option:selected').attr("id");

Answer (score 2):

Simple use:

```
$("#select_element").val();
```

If you want the text of it, then:

```
$('#select_element option:selected').text();
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/boa6me5y/)**

Comment: What is this? your option has no attribute id.

Comment: I changed <option val="04" id="04">x</option>

Comment: In this case, much more better, if you are using data-id and get `$('#select_element option:selected').data('id');`

Comment: But you did not mentioned this, and also do not need this. Check my edited answer, with jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Re your edit showing:

```
<option val="x">element1</option>
```

`val` is not a valid attribute for `option` elements. The correct attribute is `value`, or if you want a custom attribute, use a `data-` prefix (`data-val`, for instance).

So depending on whether you meant `value` or `data-val`:

#### If you meant `value`:

`$("#select_element").val()` *does* give you the value (`value` attribute) of the selected `option` element in the select box:

```js
console.log($("#select_element").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_element">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

#### If you meant `data-val`:

If you wanted to get some *other* attribute from that same `option` element, you'd do it like this:

```
var otherAttributeValue = $("#select_element option:selected").attr("data-val");
```

E.g.:

```js
var otherAttributeValue = $("#select_element option:selected").attr("data-val");
console.log(otherAttributeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_element">
  <option data-val="first" value="1">One</option>
  <option data-val="second" value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option data-val="third" value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @AlexFilatov: Both of the snippets above do work. I briefly had a non-snippet version of the second one which used an argument rather than `this` (because I misremembered jQuery's `filter` vs. `Array#filter`), perhaps that's what you were seeing? If so, hit refresh. But actually, jQuery has the pseudo-selector `:selected`, so...

Answer (score 0):

try this for get the value in the options

`$("#select_element").val()`

And try this for get the text in te option selected

```
$('#slcFoo option:selected').text()
```

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6j9r23x/)