# Getting the selected option in HTML without jQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I'm using the following function on each `<option>` to determine whether it is selected:

```
var _matches = function(el, selector) {
  var fn = el.matches || el.matchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector;
  return fn.call(el, selector);
};
```

It works fine in `jsdom` in NodeJS, and it works for the selector `:checked`  (on checkbox inputs) in the browser, but *not* for the selector `:selected`, which is odd.

I get the error (in Chrome):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': ':selected' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Don't you mean [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) rather than `:selected`? `checked` works for `<option>` too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message seems to be correct, `:selected` is not a valid selector, and even `querySelector('option:selected')` fails

The [valid pseudo selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) are

```
:active
:checked
:default
:dir()
:disabled
:empty
:enabled
:first
:first-child
:first-of-type
:fullscreen
:focus
:hover
:indeterminate
:in-range
:invalid
:lang()
:last-child
:last-of-type
:left
:link
:not()
:nth-child()
:nth-last-child()
:nth-last-of-type()
:nth-of-type()
:only-child
:only-of-type
:optional
:out-of-range
:read-only
:read-write
:required
:right
:root
:scope
:target
:valid
:visited
```

The correct psuedo class to use would be `:checked`, [**MDN says**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

> The `:checked` CSS pseudo-class selector represents any radio (`<input
>   type="radio">`), checkbox (`<input type="checkbox">`) **or option (`<option>`
>   in a `<select>`) element that is checked or toggled to an on state**.

Comment: So you use `:checked` to check for attribute `checked` in an `<input type="checkbox" "checked">`, but `:checked` to check for attribute `selected` in an `<option "selected">`.

Comment: @chrisdew - yes, options toggled to an "on state", as in being selected and having the `selected` property set to true can be captured with the `:checked` pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

I had "selected" to work with the following expression:

```
// check if any option has attribute selected
if(!dom_node.querySelectorAll("select option[selected]").length)
{
   dom_node.querySelector("select").value = "val";
}
```