# Populating Dependant Lists with JSON and JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I thought I would share this example that I created for a demo about loading nested lists apriori with jQuery.  This is a comprehensive example comprised of bits and pieces I gleaned from Stack Overflow and other readings.

I would like others to comment for improvements, and hopefully I'm not breaking any rules for the forum regarding questions.  Let me know and I will make the adjustments to the post.

Click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option/45360385#45360385) for the post I used for my first cut, but this Post has it all and more.

Click [Here](http://example.code.s3.amazonaws.com/jquerynestedlists/ajaxtest.html) 
for the Demo.

Here is the main JSON File.  Use this to create both files and name one list.json and the other list2.json

```
{  
"List":[  
{  "itemID":1,
"Sort":1,
"parentID":0,
"itemKey":100,
"itemText":"ListItem-#1"
},
{  "itemID":2,
"Sort":2,
"parentID":0,
"itemKey":200,
"itemText":"ListItem-#2"
},
{  "itemID":3,
"Sort":3,
"parentID":0,
"itemKey":300,
"itemText":"ListItem-#3"
},
{  "itemID":4,
"Sort":4,
"parentID":0,
"itemKey":400,
"itemText":"ListItem-#4"
},        
{  "itemID":5,
"Sort":5,
"parentID":100,
"itemKey":100,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#1-1"
},
{  "itemID":6,
"Sort":6,
"parentID":100,
"itemKey":200,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#1-2"
},
{  "itemID":7,
"Sort":7,
"parentID":100,
"itemKey":300,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#1-3"
},
{  "itemID":8,
"Sort":8,
"parentID":100,
"itemKey":400,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#1-4"
},
{  "itemID":9,
"Sort":9,
"parentID":200,
"itemKey":100,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#2-1"
},
{  "itemID":10,
"Sort":10,
"parentID":200,
"itemKey":200,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#2-2"
},
{  "itemID":11,
"Sort":11,
"parentID":200,
"itemKey":300,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#2-3"
},
{  "itemID":12,
"Sort":12,
"parentID":200,
"itemKey":400,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#2-4"
},
{  "itemID":13,
"Sort":13,
"parentID":300,
"itemKey":100,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#3-1"
},
{  "itemID":14,
"Sort":14,
"parentID":300,
"itemKey":200,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#3-2"
},
{  "itemID":15,
"Sort":15,
"parentID":300,
"itemKey":300,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#3-3"
},
{  "itemID":16,
"Sort":16,
"parentID":300,
"itemKey":400,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#3-4"
},
{  "itemID":17,
"Sort":17,
"parentID":400,
"itemKey":100,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#4-1"
},
{  "itemID":18,
"Sort":18,
"parentID":400,
"itemKey":200,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#4-2"
},
{  "itemID":19,
"Sort":19,
"parentID":400,
"itemKey":300,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#4-3"
},
{  "itemID":20,
"Sort":20,
"parentID":4000,
"itemKey":400,
"itemText":"Child ListItem:#4-4"
}
]
}
```

And here is the html file with the script block...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="List1"></select>
    <select id="List2"></select>
    <div></div>
</body>

<!-- Begin Script Block -->
<!-- **************************************************** -->
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//get a reference to the select element
$selectParent = $('#List1');
$selectChild = $('#List2');

// Global Collection Array that can be used to assign separate JSON Files with association array
var $APPCollections = {parentList:'',childList:''};
/**
Initial load of the main data file for selection lists
******************************************************/
$.ajax({
url: 'list.json',
dataType:'JSON',

//Success callback function for asynchronous 
success:function(data){
// Assign the JSON Data Package to the array element
$APPCollections['parentList'] = data;

//Clear Options Lists from Selects
$selectParent.html('');
$selectChild.html('');

//Iterate and assign options to both the Parent List and the default for the first selection
$.each(data.List, function(key, val){

if(val.parentID === 0)
{
    $selectParent.append('<option id="' + val.itemKey + '">' + val.itemText + '</option>');
}
else
{
    if(val.parentID === 100) /* Hard Coded for known value - not recommended */
{
    $selectChild.append('<option id="' + val.itemKey + '">' + val.itemText + '</option>');
}

}

})
},

//Error Callback if the success callback fails
error:function(){
    //Error Callback
    $selectChild.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
}
});
//****************************************************************

/** 
Another Ajax loader that populates $APPCollections association array with a second list 
Demonstrates a simple JSON collection management concept - this element is not used in concept demo
except for variable assignment
**/
$.ajax({
    url: 'list2.json',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
    $APPCollections['childList'] = data;
},
error:function(){
// Error callback
$selectChild.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
}
});
//****************************************************************

/**
OnChange Event fires when a selection is made and the child list is wiped clean and refilled with options
from the original JSON file loaded only once
**/
$( "#List1" ).change(function () {
    // Assign the Parent selected option value 
    var optionSelected = $('#List1 option:selected').attr('id');
    // Clear out the target select object
    $selectChild.html('');  
    // Iterate over the JSON list and look for parentID's to add for child options
    $.each($APPCollections['parentList'].List, function(key, val){
    if(val.parentID.toString() === optionSelected)
    {
    $selectChild.append('<option id="' + val.itemKey + '">' + val.itemText + '</option>');
    $( "div" ).text( "parentID = " + val.parentID + "  " + optionSelected );
}
});    
//******************************************************************
// End Script Block
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: These types of questions are better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You may be right, but I never search code review for examples, and I am asking for suggestions and providing a working example.  I could have answered my own question as well.  Duly noted, thank you for your comment.