# How to access custom html attributes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am aware, that similar questions have been asked before, but I can't get it to work with those older posts.

I have the following FormGroup from ReactBootstrap

```
          <Form.Group controlId="formGridWeekdays">
            <Form.Label>Wochentage</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              style={{ height: "160px" }}
              as="select"
              multiple
            >
              <option value={RRule.MO} data-number="1">Montag</option>
              <option value={RRule.TU} data-number="2">Dienstag</option>
              <option value={RRule.WE} data-number="3">Mittwoch</option>
              <option value={RRule.TH} data-number="4">Donnerstag</option>
              <option value={RRule.FR} data-number="5">Freitag</option>
              <option value={RRule.SA} data-number="6">Samstag</option>
              <option value={RRule.SU} data-number="0">Sonntag</option>
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
```

And I want to access the data-number with jQuery like that:

```
daysOfWeek: $('#formGridWeekdays').attr('data-number'),
```

But I only get undefined

Comment: You are accessing data attribute of options . So proper approach would be iterating over options with prop selected as this is multi select options. `$('#formGridWeekdays option:selected')` and use each function to iterate in which you can access data like `$(this).data('number')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - getting custom attribute from selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option)

Comment: ```daysOfWeek: {…}
​​​
0: <option value="MO" data-number="1">
​​​
1: <option value="WE" data-number="3">
​​​
2: <option value="FR" data-number="5">
​​​
length: 3``` Is what is being returned if i write the following: ```$('#formGridWeekdays option:selected').each(function(){
                        $(this).data('number')
                      })``` How would I get just an Array instead of an Object with the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can change attribute `ControId` to `id` in `Form.Group` ?

Set `id="formGridWeekdays"` and get elemento like this:

```
$('#formGridWeekdays option').data('number');
```

Comment: Yout first option does not work unfortunately, your second option returns [object Object]

Comment: `[object Object]` is the result of doing `.toString()` on an object. What does the object actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

For you get the attribute of the selected option with jquery, you need to make this:

```
$('#formGridWeekdays option:selected').attr('data-number')
```

Comment: Hey, this gives me only the number of the first selected option, is there a way to return an Array of all the numbers of the selected options?