# Show hide button on select box option style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select box what i want if there is style="color:#cccccc" in option then disable button show else enable button show.

**New Note :** i want to add disable attribute to button if there is style color attribute in option else button keep enable if there is no style color attribute  in option

```
<select class="selected" >
    <option>Bank 1</option>
    <option style="color:#cccccc">Bank 2</option>
    <option>Bank 3</option>
</select>

<button class="btn_enabled btn">Pay Enabled</button>
<button class="btn_disabled btn" disabled>Pay Disabled</button>
```

```
$(function () {
  $(".selected").on("change", function () { 
      "style" === $(this).attr() 
          ? $(".btn_enabled").show() 
          : $(".btn_enabled").hide() 
  });
});
```

```
.btn_disabled { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the selected option. Also better to use a select option as first option

```js
$(function () {
    $(".selected").on("change", function () { 
    if($(this).find(':selected').attr('style')) {
      $(".btn_enabled").show()
      $(".btn_disabled").hide()
    }
    else {
       $(".btn_disabled").show()
       $(".btn_enabled").hide()
    }
     });
});
```

```css
.btn {
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selected" >
                <option>Select Option </option>
                <option>Bank 1</option>
                <option style="color:#cccccc">Bank 2</option>
                <option>Bank 3</option>
            </select>
    
            <button class="btn_enabled btn">Pay Enabled</button>
            <button class="btn_disabled btn">Pay Disabled</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
$(".selected").on("change", function () { 
     $(".btn_enabled").show( $('option:selected', this).attr('style') );
});
```

sources:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

[jQuery - getting custom attribute from selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option)

Comment: This is the minimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".selected").on("change", function (e) {  
    $(".selected option:selected").attr("style") === "color:#cccccc" ? $(".btn_enabled").show() : $(".btn_enabled").hide() 
 });
});
```

```css
.btn_disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selected" >
    <option value="1" >Bank 1</option>
    <option value="2" style="color:#cccccc">Bank 2</option>
    <option value="3" >Bank 3</option>
</select>

<button class="btn_enabled btn">Pay Enabled</button>
<button class="btn_disabled btn" disabled>Pay Disabled</button>
```

Comment: What i want if there is color then button added disable attribute but if there is color then no change default enable

Answer (score 1):

> if there is `style="color:#cccccc"` in [one of the] `option`

You can do this with:

```
$(".selected>option[style='color:#cccccc']").length > 0
```

eg

```
$(function() {
  $(".selected>option[style='color:#cccccc']").length > 0 
    ? $(".btn_enabled").show() 
    : $(".btn_enabled").hide()
});
```

---

If you instead meant:

> if there is `style="color:#cccccc"` in [the selected] `option`

then the above can be converted with the use of `:selected`

```
$(this).find(">option:selected[style='color:#cccccc']").length > 0
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".selected").on("change", function() {
    $(this).find(">option:selected[style='color:#cccccc']").length > 0 ?
      $(".btn_enabled").show() :
      $(".btn_enabled").hide()
  });
  $(".selected").change();
});
```

```css
.btn_disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selected">
  <option>Bank 1</option>
  <option style="color:#cccccc">Bank 2</option>
  <option>Bank 3</option>
</select>

<button class="btn_enabled btn">Pay Enabled</button>
<button class="btn_disabled btn" disabled>Pay Disabled</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `$(this).find(":selected").attr('style')` to get selected option style as

```
 $(".selected").on("change", function () { 
   $(this).find(":selected").attr('style') === 'color:#cccccc' ? $(".btn_enabled").show() : $(".btn_enabled").hide() });
 });
```

```js
   

$(function () {
$(".selected").on("change", function () { $(this).find(":selected").attr('style') === 'color:#cccccc' ? $(".btn_enabled").show() : $(".btn_enabled").hide() });
    });
    
    //"style" === $(this).attr() ? $(".btn_enabled").show() : $(".btn_enabled").hide()
```

```css
.btn_disabled {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selected" >
            <option>Bank 1</option>
            <option style="color:#cccccc">Bank 2</option>
            <option>Bank 3</option>
        </select>

        <button class="btn_enabled btn">Pay Enabled</button>
        <button class="btn_disabled btn" disabled>Pay Disabled</button>
```