# Getting Attribute from option form in Java script

Tags: javascript, forms

```
<form:select multiple="false" id="zoneIds" path="id" >
      <form:option value="0" selected="selected" label="Non" />
          <c:forEach items="${zones}" var="zone">
              <form:option value="${zone.id}" label="${zone.zoneId}" test1="${zone.allowIparkBarcode}" />
          </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

I wanna get the test1 value in Javascript, I have tried the below but never worked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#zoneIds").on("change", function(){

        const dc =  $("#zoneIds").val( $(this).attr("test1") );

        console.log("TEST "  + dc)
        if(dc === "true"){
            $("#lpr").hide();
            $("#scanTicket").show();
        }else{
            $("#scanTicket").hide();
            $("#lpr").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people coming across this Q I was able to solve it by:

```
var dc = $('option:selected', this).attr('test1');
```

Instead of:

```
const dc =  $("#zoneIds").val( $(this).attr("test1") );
```