# How to retrieve id from option select onchange with Jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to retrieve the ID from a selected option. Listing Name works but not ID

HTML

```
<select id="field" name="field" class="imput listing-select-field w-select">
  <option value="">Select one...</option>
  <option id="123" value="First">First</option>
  <option id="111" value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(".listing-select-field").on("change", function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem("Listing Name", this.value);
  sessionStorage.setItem("Listing Id", $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Session storage shows only "field"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - getting custom attribute from selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230704/jquery-getting-custom-attribute-from-selected-option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `select` `change` event, `$(this)` will be the `select`, not the selected `option` - so, as confirmed, gives you `field` for all options.

You need to locate the selected option:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Listing Id", $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$( ".listing-select-field option:selected" )` to get the selected options. Then you can use `.id` on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sessionStorage.setItem("Listing Name", this.value);
```

should be

```
  sessionStorage.setItem("Listing Name", $(this).val());
```

Comment: Value is not the problem

Comment: `$(this).value` will be null/undefined.  Perhaps you meant `$(this).val()` - which is the *same* as this.value